# Using Arrays in functions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a student who is doing an assignment for C++ and I have encountered something I am very unfamiliar with. I have an int array with no size but a list of numbers. After it's creation, there is a function call inside a function that has that array as a parameter with an index in it.

For example:

```
for (int x = 0; x < CAPACITY, x++)
   functionCall(array[x]);
```

Now I am supposed to create a function so the call can work. However when I make my function:

```
void functionCall(int array[]);
```

It does not work because it cannot turn an `int` to an `int[]`.

I guess my question is, how am I supposed to get that list of numbers created originally by the array if I have to call it in my function as if it isn't an array.

Right now if I just put as an int but not an array like it wants me to do it just gives me the number 5 but not any of the numbers in the array. For example:

```
void functionCall(int array);
```

Sincere thank you for anything and I apologize if this sounds confusing.

Comment: Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Also, never name a function `functionCall`... unless it returns a structure representing a functional call in some parsing/meta-programming context.

Comment: `array[x]` is an `int`, period. If I show you an apple, can you describe the tree it came from?

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>` to represent arrays of unknown size at compile time. `std::array<int,N>` otherwise, if you know a certain value for `N`, when writing your code down.

Comment: Even if this was theoretically possible, what would the output be for the array if the user entered a literal such as 5? What if the user entered a variable not associated with an array? How would you differentiate between what is part of an array and what isn't?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You say _I have an int array with no size but a list of numbers._  (How can it have no size but it's a list?) Anyway, then you ask _how am I supposed to get that list of numbers created..._  Please read about [mcve].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I think my no size he means something like `int arr[]`, but otherwise yes, an MCVE is needed.

Comment: You need to at least show us how the array is defined and initialized, and explain what you intend functionCall to do. I have a vague guess what you mean but it's not very well described in your question. Are you intending to modify the array using functionCall?

Comment: The question is somewhat silly. Analogy: Every day my teacher gives me a page from a book. How am I supposed to get the whole book if I only get one page at a time? (and your answer must work even if the page wasn't actually from a book in the first place)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> functionCall(array[x]);
> ```

This passes the x<sup>th</sup> element in the array to the function, so a single `int`.

```
array[2] = 5;
functionCall(array[2]); // This is the same as functionCall(5);
```

So in the function, you get the current element of the array. Not the array itself.

You cannot get the list inside the function, because you only give a single element of that list each time you call it.

Comment: **"I guess my question is, how am I supposed to get that list of numbers created originally by the array if I have to call it in my function as if it isn't an array."** - Your answer doesn't address this. (Even a simple yes or no would do)

Comment: You cannot get the list inside the function, because you only give a single element of that list each time you call it.

Comment: Don't tell me, write it in your answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess, I suspect you are looking for something like the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below:

```
#include <iostream>

void functionCall(int v) {
    std::cout << v << " ";
}
void func(int array[], size_t CAPACITY) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < CAPACITY; x++)
        functionCall(array[x]);
}
int main() {
    int list[] = { 1,2,3,4,3,0, 42 };
    func(list, std::distance(std::begin(list), std::end(list)));
    return 0;
}
```